# Toshiba satellite Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless

The laptop had wifi with Win 10 but not now that I installed Ubuntu in place of Win 10.
It works OK with the ethernet cable but no says 'no wifi adaptor' when I remove Ethernet cable

The output of lspci shows that I have an ethernet controller Realtek RTL810eX and an 'unassigned' class Realtek RTS5229. I have assumed that I need the RTL810eX and have tried to download it in the same way as shown on this site dated 19th April 2019 how to install RTL8723DE for an HP laptop but it didn't work for me.

```
alan@alan-SATELLITE-L50t-B:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0e)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Paste the output of `sudo lshw -C network` in your answer. Use pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/

Comment: The RTL810eX is your wired Ethernet controller; but for WiFi, we need to find your WiFi controller. Please highlight the result of that command line mentioned by @Idias then do Ctrl-Shift-C to copy the text content. Then, return here, click [edit], and paste the text into your question, instead of using pastebin, so all the facts we need are visible in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)